# Power BI Compare two tables and display missing rows from the first table

Tags: datatables, powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I am facing a challenge in powerBI. I have two different tables that have hundreds of rows in them. These two tables are connected by a common column (Name). I want to compare two tables on the attribute name and then display the rows of table-1 whose names are not present in Table-2. It would be great if anyone can help me in this regard.

My data looks like this:

**Table 1**

```
Name | Occupation | Address             
Joe  |    Teacher |    Dallas              
Ann  |    Hunter  |    Houston             
Saly |    Artist  |    Novi
```

**Table 2**

```
 Name | Marital Status | Phone
Saly  |  Married       |  3132485889
Niky  |  Single        |  9831773846
```

**Desired Output**

```
Name | Occupation | Address
Joe  |    Teacher |    Dallas
Ann  |    Hunter  |    Houston
```

Comment: Table 2 just looks like a pipe separated list of values. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to filter for blanks in the "Name" column of the second table. See the below screenshot.

Create a grid which has all the columns from both tables. "Name 2" is the Name column from the second table. In the "Filters" pane, for "Name 2" column, choose "Blank".

[image]